# Sticky footer with comment box like WhatsApp

Tags: javascript, html, comments, whatsapp, sticky-footer

I was just wondering, can we add a sticky footer with comment box like WhatsApp on to our website. And to display the comment on the same page. Is there way to do so?

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en-US">

 <head>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>ChatRoom</title>      </head>

 <body>     <div id="navigation">       <a href="#">test</a>    </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS of my site

```
    body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  
    font-family: Lucida Grande, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  /* Adds shadow to the bottom of the bar */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
  /* Adds the transparent background */
  background-color: rgba(60, 179, 113, 1.0);
  color: rgba(60, 179, 113, 1.0);
}

#navigation a {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#content {
    width: 600px;
    padding-top: 70px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#content img {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Can anyone help me with it please?

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure you can do that. For the sticky footer the trick is to position the footer `absolute` and do `bottom:0` so that the footer sticks to the bottom with respect to the container. Also you would need to write some Javascript logic to manipulate the comments.

Here is a rough [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/49pocp2L/) implementation for the example. If you have any questions ask. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, if that's all you have, there isn't a way to do so.

You need server logic to accomplish your task.